# \ignorespaces vs \relax

Tags: primitives

In the TeXbook, there is a macro called `\ignorespaces`:

> `\ignorespaces ⟨optional spaces⟩`. TeX reads (and expands) tokens, doing nothing until reaching one that is not a ⟨space token⟩.

And there is another macro called `\relax` for which TeX does nothing.

Is `\ignorespaces` redundant since it seems that `\relax` can achieve `\ignorespaces`'s functionality? See the following example:

```
a\ignorespaces b\ignorespaces
    c\ignorespaces   \hskip1em d

a\relax b\relax
    c\relax   \hskip1em d
```

The effect is the same.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The primitive `\ignorespaces` gobbles the following space tokens (explicit or implicit) and performs macro expansion. It won't ignore glue specification, so the `\hskip1em` will remain.

Your example is misleading, because in

```
a\ignorespaces b
```

there's no space to be ignored. Nor there is a space in

```
a\relax b
```

Try

```
a\ignorespaces\space b

a\relax\space b
```

instead and you'll see the difference.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

`\ignorespaces` is not a macro it is an unexpandable primitive (like `\relax`)

`\relax` does nothing when executed, `\ignorespaces` causes following space *tokens* to be ignored.

Your example did not show a difference as there are no space tokens after `\relax`  the space *character* in the input is used to terminate the command name then discarded without being tokenized.

[image]

```
a\relax\space b

a\ignorespaces\space b

\uppercase{x\relax} y

\uppercase{x\ignorespaces} y

\bye
```

Answer (score 7):

They work differently in definitions:

```
\documentclass{article}
 
 \begin{document}
 
 \newcommand\testa[1]{test #1\ignorespaces} \testa{a} b 
 
 \newcommand\testb[1]{test #1\relax} \testb{a} b 
 \end{document}
```

[image]